# No graphql endpoint provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-api-gateway

I'm having trouble with using he graphQL from AWS.

I can successfully login and confirm the user with Cognito as I can see it in the console.

Sign in with Cognito:

```
async signIn(email, password) {
      try {
          //sign in the user
          const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);
          AlertHelper.show('info', 'yups', user);
      }
      //If not a user then display message
      catch (error) {
          AlertHelper.show("warn", "User not found", "Please create an account");
      }
  }
```

Returns a successful message then I call another function to call the graphQL api:

```
async check() {
    try {
      const userInfo = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({bypassCache:true})
      console.log("User info: ",userInfo)

    //If there is a user
      if(userInfo){

        const userData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getUser));

        console.log("User Data: ",userData);
      }
    }

    catch (err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err)
    }
}
```

Here is the error even though the user info is correct:

```
  errors: [ [GraphQLError: No graphql endpoint provided.] ] }
```

Here is my AWS Exports:

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "eu-west-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "eu-west-1_xxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "oauth": {}
};

export default awsmobile;
```

Get User:

```
export const getUser = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetUser($id: ID!) {
    getUser(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      coins
      description
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

Im tearing my hair out here please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I figured it out:

1. add this to your aws-exports:

"aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://ENDPOINT_GRAPHQL.com/graphql",
"aws_appsync_region": "eu-west-1",
"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",

2. This is how you query:

imports:

```
import * as mutations from '../../../graphql/mutations';
import * as queries from '../../../graphql/queries';
```

Function:

```
async check() {
    try {
      const userInfo = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({bypassCache:true})
      console.log("User info: ",userInfo)

    //If there is a user
      if(userInfo){
        const oneTodo = await API.graphql({ query: queries.getUser, variables: { id: '111' }});

        console.log("one todos: ",oneTodo); // result: { "data": { "listTodos": { "items": [/* ..... */] } } }

      }
    }

    catch (err) {
      console.log('error: ', err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, a simple `amplify pull` updated the `aws-exports.js` file and added the necessary GraphQL endpoint and other necessary config:

```js
const awsmobile = {
    //...
    aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint: "https://xxx.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    aws_appsync_region: "ap-southeast-2",
    aws_appsync_authenticationType: "API_KEY",
    aws_appsync_apiKey: "xxx"
};
```

Then in my front-end it worked as normal:

```js
import { createUserDataItems } from "../graphql/mutations";
import { API, Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import config from "../aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(config);
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I will try that too

Answer (score 0):

"aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://xxx.appsync-api.ap-northeast2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
"aws_appsync_region": "ap-northeast-2",
"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
//if you use API key

"aws_appsync_apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"aws_appsync_dangerously_connect_to_http_endpoint_for_testing": true

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).